# Save GCM Push message in SharedPreferences

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, sharedpreferences

I send GCM push notifications to my android app and when i click on the intent i get the message displayed in My Activity. After viewing the message, when the Activity is destroyed or killed the message is no longer display in my activity. I want to save the message in SharedPreferences so that i can view it whenever i resume that activity. I seem to get it right but the message does not display when i close and relaunch my activity.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_health_notifications);
    msgET = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);

    String userEntry = msgET.getText().toString();

    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(Config.STORE_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

    editor.putString(Config.USER_TIP, userEntry);

    editor.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing the message in `onCreate` is not correct. The message is not yet set at this point.

Instead store it in `onStop` and read it back to the view in `onStart`.